# How to replace enum in Android?

Tags: android, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
public enum Type {
    VIDEO(10,"video"),
    AUDIO(11,"audio");

   int code;
   String desc;

   Type(int code,String desc){
       this.code = code;
       this.desc = desc;
   }
}
```

**But** ,   Enumerations are not recommended in Android，How to do it with typedef, or is there another better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can using `@IntDef` but still need method to convert `code` to `desc`. But take a look article from Google Developer, he said now enum isn't a big deal, not overhead memory and already optimize by R8 read [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/when-using-enums-and-r8-3f8f314c0a13)

```
   @Retention(SOURCE)
   @IntDef({VIDEO,AUDIO})
   public @interface Type {}
   public static final int VIDEO = 10;
   public static final int AUDIO = 11;

   @Type int type
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example enum, you don't really need `desc` value, since you can use `name()` method (and even `toString()`), for example

```
final String desc = Type.VIDEO.name();
```

you could turn String result to lower/upper case as your convenience.

On the other hand, @IntDef is a way of replacing an integer enum where there's a parameter that should only accept explicit int values. If you have a parameterized enum with multiple hardwired values, like yours `VIDEO(10,"video", "etc..."`) you should consider use the enum.

You can also create an annotation using a custom class and then use it in the same way as someone mentioned in this response [Convert parametized Enum to Enumerated Annotation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512818/convert-parametized-enum-to-enumerated-annotation-in-android)

I have never tried R8 yet, as @Công Hải mentioned, and evaluate its performance   on enums. You will find multiple articles about how bad are enums for your app, and they most seem quite right. But don't avoid it strictly. I would try to use @IntDef or @StringDef, as much as I could, but it is not always simple. My adivice, you should analyze if you want to lose code readability for avoiding enums, or suffer for the overhead they may cause. You can always try.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are no longer an issue for Android thanks to the replacement of Dalvik as runtime environment by ART. You can find more information about it in this Google IO video from 2018: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrMw7MEgADk&t=849s - If you don't want to watch the whole vid you can fast forward to the minute 14:09.

Plus, thanks to R8, most enums are optimised at compile time too: https://jakewharton.com/r8-optimization-enum-ordinals-and-names/

So go ahead and your Enums :) they make the code more concise, easier to understand and less error-prone than other options.